# Getting constant length retrieve time constant with immutable lists in a functional programming context

Tags: haskell, f#, functional-programming, ocaml, immutability

I am currently facing the problem of having to make my calculations based on the length of a given list. Having to iterate over all the elements of the list to know its size is a big performance penalty as I'm using rather big lists.

What are the suggested approaches to the problem?

I guess I could always carry a size value together with the list so I know beforehand its size without having to compute it at the call site but that seems a brittle approach. I could also define a own type of list where each node has as property its the lists' size but then I'd lose the leverage provided by my programming language's libraries for standard lists.

How do you guys handle this on your daily routine?

I am currently using F#. I am aware I can use .NET's mutable (array) lists, which would solve the problem. I am way more interested, though, in the purely immutable functional approach.

Comment: Hmmm ... I guess list is not the correct data structure for this case. Lists are ok for some limited set of values, but if those values count becomes large and large you will get into performance trouble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The built-in F# list type doesn't have any caching of the length and there is no way to add that in some clever way, so you'll need to define your own type. I think that writing a wrapper for the existing F# `list` type is probably the best option.

This way, you can avoid explicit conversions - when you wrap the list, it will not actually copy it (as in svick's implementation), but the wrapper can easily cache the `Length` property:

```
open System.Collections

type LengthList<'T>(list:list<'T>) =
  let length = lazy list.Length
  member x.Length = length.Value
  member x.List = list
  interface IEnumerable with
    member x.GetEnumerator() = (list :> IEnumerable).GetEnumerator()
  interface seq<'T> with  //'
    member x.GetEnumerator() = (list :> seq<_>).GetEnumerator()

[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
module LengthList =
  let ofList l = LengthList<_>(l)
  let ofSeq s = LengthList<_>(List.ofSeq s)
  let toList (l:LengthList<_>) = l.List
  let length (l:LengthList<_>) = l.Length
```

The best way to work with the wrapper is to use `LengthList.ofList`  for creating `LengthList` from a standard F# list and to use `LengthList.toList` (or just the `List`) property before using any functions from the standard `List` module.

However, it depends on the complexity of your code - if you only need length in a couple of places, then it may be easier to keep it separately and use a tuple `list<'T> * int`.

Answer (score 5):

> How do you guys handle this on your daily routine?

We don't, because this isn't a problem in daily routine.  It sounds like a problem perhaps in limited domains.

If you created the lists recently, then you've probably already done O(N) work, so walking the list to get its length is probably not a big deal.

If you're making a few very large lists that are then not 'changing' much (obviously never changing, but I mean changing set of references to heads of lists that are used in your domain/algorithm), then it may make sense to just have a dictionary off to the side of reference-to-list-head*length tuples, and consult the dictionary when asking for lengths (doing the real work to walk them when needed, but caching results for future asks about the same list).

Finally, if you really are dealing with some algorithm that needs to be constantly updating the lists in play and constantly consulting the lengths, then create your own list-like data type (yes, you'll also need to write map/filter and any others).

(Very generally, I think it is typically best to use the built-in data structures 99.99% of the time.  In the 0.01% of the time where you are developing an algorithm or bit of code that needs to be very highly optimized, then almost always you need to abandon built-in data structures (which are good enough for most cases) and use a custom data structure designed to solve the exact problem you are working on.  Look to wikipedia or Okasaki's "'Purely Functional Data Structures" for ideas and inspriation in that case.  But rarely go to that case.)

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why carying the length around is a brittle approach. Try something like this (Haskell):

```
data NList a = NList Int [a]

nNil :: NList [a]
nNil = NList 0 []

nCons :: a -> NList a -> NList a
nCons x (NList n xs) = NList (n+1) (x:xs)

nHead :: NList a -> a
nHead (NList _ (x:_)) = x

nTail :: NList a -> NList a
nTail (NList n (_:xs)) = NList (n-1) xs

convert :: [a] -> NList a
convert xs = NList (length xs) xs
```

and so on. If this is in a library or module, you can make it safe (I think) by not exporting the constructor `NList`.

It may also be possible to coerce GHC into memoizing `length`, but I'm not sure how or when.

Comment: The problem of this is, that your lists do no longer stream, if you refer to the length.

Comment: @FUZxxl I'm not sure what you mean by stream; obviously you can't use this for infinite lists, but you can't run `length` on infinite lists either...

Comment: I think it has something do to with the fact that `NList` is not recursively defined, while regular Haskell lists are. For regular lists, `tail` is simply a matter of deconstructing the cons cell, while for `nTail`, you need to deconstruct it and reconstruct another `NList`.

Answer (score 1):

In F#, most `List` functions have an equivalent `Seq` functions. That means, you can just implement your own immutable linked list that carries the length with each node. Something like this:

```
type MyList<'T>(item : Option<'T * MyList<'T>>) =

    let length =
        match item with
        | None -> 0
        | Some (_, tail) -> tail.Length + 1

    member this.Length = length

    member private this.sequence =
        match item with
        | None -> Seq.empty
        | Some (x, tail) ->
            seq {
                yield x
                yield! tail.sequence
            }

    interface seq<'T> with
        member this.GetEnumerator() =
            (this.sequence).GetEnumerator()
        member this.GetEnumerator() =
            (this.sequence :> System.Collections.IEnumerable).GetEnumerator()

module MyList =
    let rec ofList list =
        match list with
        | [] -> MyList None
        | head::tail -> MyList(Some (head, ofList tail))
```